# how to change my app's target API level from 29 to 31 in ionic android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have updated my config.xml

```
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="32" />
    <preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="32" />
```

But the actual built project is still targeting 29.

I have also tried to remove the android platform and then reinstall it @10 or @11. It doesn't change this.

Is there anything else I would need to do to apply the change?

Comment: When you open project in android studio you can change and build it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out what I need to do is to do the following:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@10
```

And then it automatically become 31.

It seems that simply change the preference in `config.xml` won't do anything.

Comment: android@10.1.2 is installed when "add android@10", thanks